# Decorator Pattern from Head First Book

Tags: design-patterns

I am working on a excursive from book Head First Design Patterns . 
Problem:
Use Decorator pattern on starbuzz application to add size to this existing code

Beverage.Class

```html
package CoffeHouse.drinks;

import CoffeHouse.drinks.sizedBevrage.Size;

/**
 * trying to implement decorator pattern and understand why and how it is implemented
 * @author praveen
 *
 */
public abstract class Bevrage {
 
 Size drinkSize = null;
 
 String description = "Unknown Drink";
 
 public String getDescription(){
  return description;
 }
 
 public Size getSize(){
  return drinkSize;
 }
 
 public abstract double cost();
 
}
```

Expresso Class

```html
public class Expresso extends Bevrage {
 
 public Expresso(){
  this.description = "Expresso";
 }
 
 @Override
 public double cost() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 1.19;
 }

}
```

Condiment class

```html
package CoffeHouse.condiments;

import CoffeHouse.drinks.Bevrage;

public abstract class CondimentDecorator extends Bevrage{
 public abstract String getDescription();
}
```

Mocha Class

```html
package CoffeHouse.condiments;

import CoffeHouse.drinks.Bevrage;

public class Mocha extends CondimentDecorator{
 
 private Bevrage bevrage;
 
 public Mocha(Bevrage be){
  this.bevrage  = be;
 }
 @Override
 public String getDescription() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return this.bevrage.getDescription()+",Mocha";
 }

 @Override
 public double cost() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return this.bevrage.cost()+0.15;
 }

}
```

We are asked to edit this code so as to add size of the drink and determine the cost of condiments based on size. The issue I have is if I add size methods to beverage abstract class the mocha class also inherits it . I don't want to give mocha class the ability to change size of drink . Is this limitation of decorator pattern or is there a workaround it

Answer (score 1):

You have 4 classes of coffee:

- Houseblend
- DarkRoast
- Espresso
- Decaf

You also have 4 condiments, that you can add to a coffee:

- Milk
- Mocha
- Soy
- Whip

The only method you implement is `getSize()`, so you are not setting the size of the drink.

Instead each of the 4 condiments can get the size of the drink so "it knows" how much of this condiment you need to add to a beverage. A small DarkRoast does need only a little bit of milk for say 0.10$, while a venti-sized DarkRoast would need more milk, which then would cost 0.20$.

So indeed Mocha (and all the other condiment-classes) **need** the `getSize()`-method in order to know the size of the drink. With this knowledge they tan can define the cost for the quantity of the condiment, that has been added to the beverage. (see the solution on the last page of chapter 3 [Head First Patterns second edition 2014])

The condiments are not able to set / change the size of the beverage. Therefore it was on purpose, that Mocha inherits the `getSize()`-method and needs no workaround.